# Appropriate test for ball and urn problem

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho

What would be good test to use to solve the following problem?

I have a large urn filled with 25 different types of colored balls, the distribution of which is unknown, but it is known that the are not all of equal abundance. The total number of balls in the urn is very large.

In trying to determine the underlying distribution of balls in the urn, I have sampled from the urn using several ball-counting robots, each of which uses a different method for detecting ball color or number that may each introduce some bias into the result. Unfortunately, the methods do not all sample the same number of balls.

I would like to compare the methods (robots) of sampling to one another, to determine which methods produce the most similar representation of the balls.

What would be a reasonable statistical test for determining the degree to which the samples produced under the different methods correlate with one another?

Would pairwise Spearman's Rank correlations work?

Comment: It would seem your concern is about obtaining a good estimate of the distribution, but "similar representation" implies neither accurate nor unbiased.  Are you sure this is the question you need to be asking?  Or should you perhaps be asking about how to *calibrate* your robots so you can assess their accuracy (or compensate for biases)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; this scenario is based on real world data in which we have no means of calibrating the the robots. The balls in question are readcounts obtained from sequencing different species in a community, and unfortunately there is no unbiased way of determining the actual content of the community outside our methods.

Comment: For this reason, our current goal is simply to determine the correlation between the data produced by the different methods.